# Question about my vue test app with supabase

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, supabase

I have a question about if i am correctly getting one value of the array supabase gives.

I use this code to do this

```
countries.value = parseInt(countries.value.map(({ aantal }) => aantal));
```

If i dont wrap it in a parsInt i get the number like: [2000]
So when i wrap it i get only 2000. Which is correct.
I also tested it with using .toString. Also works

My question:

Is doing it this way correct? Becuase i first was really confused why the number was wrapped in square brackets []

The complete code

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
  import { supabase } from "./lib/supabaseClient";

  const countries = ref();

  async function getCountries() {
    const { data } = await supabase.from("count").select("aantal");

    countries.value = data;
    console.log({ data });

    countries.value = parseInt(countries.value.map(({ aantal }) => aantal));
  }
  async function updateplus() {
    countries.value++;
    console.log("update", countries.value);
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("count")
      .update({ aantal: countries.value })
      .eq("id", 1)
      .select();

    console.log("update", { data, error });
  }
  onMounted(() => {
    getCountries();
  });
  const nummber = countries.value;
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ countries }}
    {{ nummber }}
    Count
  </div>
  <div><button @click="updateplus()">Plus 1</button></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always expecting only one value then you should be using `.single()` along with that query. If however you are expecting zero to one row then you should use `.maybeSingle()`. If you don't use either of these methods then you will always get the data returned as an array.

```
const { data } = await supabase.from("count").select("aantal").maybeSingle();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked indeed. Stupid of me

Answer (score 0):

I used this it look better

```
 async function getCountries() {
    const { data } = await supabase
      .from("numbers")
      .select("aantal")
      .limit(1)
      .single();

    countries.value = data.aantal;
    console.log({ data });
  }
```